# Snort Parallelization Techniques and its effect on DDOS detection capability

Tags: ddos, detection, snort

I want to ask a query about snort parallelization.

1) Can snort detection rate remains same for all attacks after parallelisation?

2) As the parallelisation of netowrk traffic in each core is based on flow, what are the problems that can be faced in detecting multi session attacks ; because many applciation level attacks occur in multi sessions.

3) The attacks that may occur in multi sessions can be like DDOS Syn Flood?

Comment: You have 3 questions here - can you separate them out into separate questions please. (I think 3 has been answered her before)